# How can a small bug dart around in a slug's slime?

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates

Last year I saw a large slug in the garden, and when I looked closer there was a small creature moving around rapidly, and I mean really fast (hence my use of the word "dart" in the question title - it was no exaggeration!), on the slug's surface below the slime.

What could this creature have been, and how on Earth could it have moved so fast through the slug's sticky slime?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, your question isn't clear. To [identify an organism](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) we need: a detailed description (preferable including clear photos), location, size, and appropriate tags. Also try not to leap to conclusions (e.g. that this was a parasite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a mite, I have seen these before.

They can move (swim) faster than the slug.

Probably *Riccardoella oudemansi* since it is the only slug mite I can find a mention of.

Article on similar snail mite below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccardoella_limacum